# Reduce query time in fetching random row sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

In Android, i have a more than 90,000 record in sqlite database from that i want to fetch 4 different random row, but it is taking so much time can any body help me how can we reduce that time because it is taking more than 5 to 6 seconds in my mobile phone

the query is below

```
   select * from Employee RANDOM LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Can you have some way to pass some random numbers to the query? The numbers will be the primary key values in the query. You can generate them using a programming language. It will be faster I think.

Comment: Did you try `select * from Employee order by RANDOM() LIMIT 4`

Comment: but P5Coder how can i pass 4 random number in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query does not actually fetch random rows, it fetches the first four rows because it is interpreted like this, i.e., "RANDOM" is used as a table alias:

```
select * from Employee as RANDOM LIMIT 4
```

To reorder a set randomly, you have to use `ORDER BY RANDOM()`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4
```

However, this is not efficient (as you have seen) because it cannot be optimized because the return values of `RANDOM()` are unpredictable.

---

To fetch random Employee records faster, you need

1. some integer ID column (let's assume you called it `_id`), and
2. an index on that column (this is done automatically for a `PRIMARY KEY` column).

To get four random records, first get the largest `_id` value from the database:

```
SELECT MAX(_id) FROM Employee
```

Then generate four random integers between 1 and that value in your code, and execute this fast  query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE _id IN (?,?,?,?)
```

If employees can be deleted, the it is possible that some `_id` value does not exist in the table.
In that case, you have to create a new random number and try again for another record.